# Incomplete ctags generated , but why?

Tags: vim, tags, glib, ctags

I tried to create taglist for glib ,  so i tried the following:

```
%> cd ~/.vim/tags/
%> ctags -o glib -R --sort=yes /usr/include/glib-2.0/
%> grep g_hash glib
g_hash_table_freeze /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h  125;"   d
g_hash_table_thaw   /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/ghash.h  134;"   d
```

Well , things like `g_hash_table_new()` wasn't included here , did i miss something important here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this works:

```
ctags -o glib.tags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --sort=yes glib-2.0
```

(Exuberant Ctags 5.7, Win 32)

The important option here is `+p`. This adds function prototypes to the tags file.
This is necessary since you scan only `.h`-files and not the `.c`/`.cpp`-files. Thus
ctags "sees" only the prototypes.

`g_hash_table_freeze` and `g_hash_table_thaw` are tagged without the `+p` option because they are just defines, not function prototypes.